# React Native Permissions. PermissionAwareActivity problem

Tags: react-native, android-permissions

For the sake of testing and training I have this code.

```
async function testperm () {

  try {

    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA, {
            title: 'Cool Photo App Camera Permission',
            message:
              'Cool Photo App needs access to your camera ' +
              'so you can take awesome pictures.',
            buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
            buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
            buttonPositive: 'OK',
        },          
    );

    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      alert('Camera ready to be used');
    } else {
      console.log('Permission denied');
    }
}

catch (err) {
    alert (err);
}

}
```

And the product is this

[image]

I can't find any documentation to solve this problem.
The code is based on this official tutorial: 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/permissionsandroid

Does anyone know how to solve this.
The Backend for my app is made in JAVA so if there is something I need to do in it no problem. But I don't have any Idea what to do.

Thanks.

I forgot to tell. Using Expo V 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using expo then this will do your work:

```
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';



async testperm() {

  try {

    const { status, expires, permissions } = await Permissions.askAsync(
      Permissions.CAMERA
    );
    if (status !== 'granted') {
      alert('Hey! You have not enabled selected permissions');
    }
    if (status === 'granted') {
      alert('camera permission granted');
    }
  }

  catch (err) {
    alert(err);
  }

}

componentDidMount = () => {
  this.testperm();
}
```

even you can ask multiple permissions (https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/permissions/)

Comment: Thanks. That worker fine for the part of permissions. Now comes the part of using the camera but that's another subject.